# Is it possible to draw on a QBitmap with OpenGL?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, bitmap, waveform

*Information beside question:*
I'm using QBitmap's for precalculating waveforms images of audio signals. They're generated with a QPolygon which is drawn by a painter for the bitmap (off-screen). The painter however needs to much time for that, I do not know why.

Maybe it's because I'm drawing about 2^19 points into a bitmap with (only!) 2000 x 1000 pixels so that's why I thought the GPU could be better in doing such things.

Beside the bad precalculating performance this solution gives me during viewing waveforms a great performance (However If you have a better solution for my goal you feel free to give me information to this topic too).

**Actual question:**
***How can I draw on a QBitmap with OpenGL? Is that even possible? If not, how could I reach the same result (precalculating a bitmap) with OpenGL and QT?***

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglfunctions-3-0.html#glBitmap

Comment: Thanks for that, I haven't been lucky with googling that. I'll look into it

Comment: I think that it's a direct wrapper for the OpenGL calls you need.